# Select elements in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with random values like this:

```
In [493]: arr = np.random.randint(-10,10,(5,7))
In [494]: arr
Out[494]: 
array([[ -5,  -6,  -7,  -1,  -8,  -8, -10],
       [ -9,   1,  -3,  -9,   3,   8,  -1],
       [  6,  -7,   4,   0,  -4,   4,  -2],
       [ -3, -10,  -2,   7,  -4,   2,   2],
       [ -5,   5,  -1,  -7,   7,   5,  -7]])
```

Now, I want to do a filter method:

```
if (elem > -3 && elme < 3), elem <- 0
```

How to implement this method in numpy without using for loop?

Comment: In questions with random data, it can be helpful to set a value for `np.random.seed(value)` so that your problem can be reproducible as-is.

Comment: `arr[(arr > -3) & (arr < 3)] = 0` . Look for boolean indexing. (you can start from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html)).

Comment: What's `elem <- 0` supposed to mean? Is it another condition?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Set `elem` to zero